# Realm and the lack of LIMIT: How a to do a stepped delete operation?

Tags: android, realm

I'm having somewhat of a problem with some missing features in Realm for Android. I understand the preferred patterns don't really require a LIMIT-type of function but I have a very specific use case where I don't see an immediate solution with the current API.

I have a Realm where I save LogMessage objects in. The enclosing app can call a `sendLog()` method, which will add a new LogMessage to the Realm.

The app can also sync these LogMessages in batches to a server and deletes the ones that are already synced. Now here's the problem:

Say I get all LogMessages and want to sync them in batches of 100:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        RealmResults<LogMessage> result = realm.where(LogMessage.class).findAll();
int resultSize = result.size();
int logsPerRequest = 100;

while(result.size() > 0) {
       final List<LogMessage> pageResult = result.subList(0 , Math.min(logsPerRequest, resultSize));
       JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
       JsonElement array = gson.toJsonTree(pageResult, new TypeToken<List<LogMessage>>(){}.getType());
       json.add("events", array);

       RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
       Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url(extras.getString(URL, ""))
                  .post(body)
                  .build();

       //Try to sync
       final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
       if (response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
             //Delete the synced log messages
             realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                      @Override
                      public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                //WHAT NOW?
                      }
             });



      }
}
```

You can see the problem. I can't just call `deleteFromRealm()` on `pageResult` because it's an unmanaged list. There's also no method where you can call `deleteFromRealm()` on the realm itself and pass in a list of objects to delete.

And I can't call `deleteFromRealm()` on `result` because that would delete the entire list while I may yet have LogMessages to sync.

How can I best fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility would be moving the entirety of the logic into a single transaction, thus ensuring that the Realm instance and the RealmResults is up to date on request

```
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                int logsPerRequest = 100;

                while(realm.where(LogMessage.class).count() > 0) {
                    RealmResults<LogMessage> result = realm.where(LogMessage.class).findAll();
                    final List<LogMessage> pageResult = result.subList(0, Math.min(logsPerRequest, result.size()));
                    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                    JsonElement array = gson.toJsonTree(pageResult, new TypeToken<List<LogMessage>>() {}.getType());
                    json.add("events", array);

                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(extras.getString(URL, "")).post(body).build();

                    //Try to sync
                    final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    if(response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        //Delete the synced log messages
                        for(int i = pageResult.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            LogMessage message = pageResult.get(i);
                            message.deleteFromRealm();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
```

---

---

Another possibility would be (sigh... I dislike recommending this approach) to add force refresh to your code via the internal API (v1.2.0).

```
package io.realm; // <---- this is important 

public class RealmRefresh {
    public static void refreshRealm(Realm realm) {
        Message message = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = HandlerControllerConstants.LOCAL_COMMIT;
        realm.handlerController.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

With which you can do

```
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        RealmRefresh.refreshRealm(realm);
        int logsPerRequest = 100;

        while(realm.where(LogMessage.class).count() > 0){
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    RealmResults<LogMessage> result = realm.where(LogMessage.class).findAll();
                    final List<LogMessage> pageResult = result.subList(0, Math.min(logsPerRequest, result.size()));
                    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                    JsonElement array = gson.toJsonTree(pageResult, new TypeToken<List<LogMessage>>() {}.getType());
                    json.add("events", array);

                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(extras.getString(URL, "")).post(body).build();

                    //Try to sync
                    final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    if(response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        //Delete the synced log messages
                        for(int i = pageResult.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            LogMessage message = pageResult.get(i);
                            message.deleteFromRealm();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            RealmRefresh.refreshRealm(realm);
        }
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
```

As much as I dislike tinkering with internal API, this one seems more robust to me.

Comment: So you're saying that there's no other way to delete a sublist from RealmResults than to loop through every single item and delete it separately? That sucks. :) There really should be some kind of method where you can pass a list of managed objects and just delete that.

Comment: Well `RealmResults` does have `deleteAllFromRealm`, but AFAIK there is no way to delete a subset of them without loop and one-by-one